# How to access object of a derived class by base class reference in c++?

Tags: c++

I would read The following lines in C++:The complete reference Book. I Did no get clear idea with that.

```
References to Derived Types

Similar to the situation as described for pointers earlier, a base class reference can be
used to refer to an object of a derived class. The most common application of this is
found in function parameters. A base class reference parameter can receive objects of
the base class as well as any other type derived from that base.
```

I Have doubt with than following code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class base
{
protected:
    int i;
public:
    void seti(int num){i=num;}
    int geti(){return i;}
};

class derived:public base
{
protected:
    int j;
public:
    void setj(int num){j=num;}
    int getj(){return j;}
};


void refe(base &ob)
{
    ob.seti(1);
    ob.setj(2);
}

int main()
{
   derived d;
   refe(d);

   cout<<d.geti();
   cout<<"\n"<<d.getj();

   return 0;
}
```

When i compile The code It will through the following error:

```
D:\Users\srilakshmikanthan.p\Documents\source code\ex.cpp||In function 'void refe(base&)':|
D:\Users\srilakshmikanthan.p\Documents\source code\ex.cpp|28|error: 'class base' has no member named 
'setj'
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===
```

and i also cast like this in function refe() ((derived *)ob).setj(2); this also shows following error:

```
D:\Users\srilakshmikanthan.p\Documents\source code\ex.cpp||In function 'void refe(base&)':|
D:\Users\srilakshmikanthan.p\Documents\source code\ex.cpp|28|error: invalid cast from type 'base' to 
type 'derived*'
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

So please explain this lines in that book.

Comment: For polymorphism to work you need to use `virtual` functions. And *override* those functions in the child classes, not create new functions.

Comment: As for the cast, first of all all C-style casting should be seen as a warning that you do something wrong. Secondly, in the `refe` function `ob` is a *reference* not a pointer, so you need to cast it as a reference (as in `static_cast<derived&>(ob)`).

Comment: This means that references to derived classes can be implicitly converted to references to base classes. This does not mean that you can use references to base class to access members of the derived class. To invoke derived behavior through a base class reference, you either have to use `virtual` semantics, or cast the reference back to a reference to a derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call only virtual function of derived class from base class reference see this,

```
#include<iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"Base";
    }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    void fun()override
    {
        std::cout<<"Derived";
    }
};

void myfun(Base &ob)
{
    ob.fun();
}

int main()
{
    Derived ob;
    myfun(ob);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Derived
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.266 s
Press any key to continue.
```

> And i also cast like this in function refe() ((derived *)ob).setj(2); this also shows following error:

Cast to `((derived &)ob).setj(2);` this will work because it is not pointer it is reference